# How can i get a range of number of characters in SQL Server using wildcard characters

Tags: sql-server, wildcard

I have a query where i need to filter the value whether it has 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 characters not more than that. I know this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE col LIKE '______' OR col LIKE '_______' and so on..
```

Is there a general way to filter the number of characters. what if it varies a long range? Do i need to put this OR for that much conditions

Comment: select * from table where len(col) between 6 and 9

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and think that filtering by length (Y) is the solution. When Y doesn't work you ask about Y, not the actual problem X. Why do you need to do that at all? Such a query can't use indexes and be forced to scan all rows in the table. Using wildcards *won't* allow it to use indexes either.

Comment: You coudl use `LEN(Col) between 6 and 9` but that won't use indexes either. Why do you care about the length? Does the field contain different types of data perhaps? That would be a design problem. You should use different fields for different types of data, if not different tables. You could also add a separate field to store the category/type of the data. This would allow you to use indexes and perform the search thousands of times faster

Answer (score 1):

[LEN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
where len(col) between 6 and 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if you want minimum 6 char and max 9 char

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE length(col) between 6 and 9
```

if you want at most 9 char

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE length(col) <= 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [len](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE len(col) between 6 and 9
```